# Is there any pure CSS only solution to keep footer fixed at page bottom in Mobile Web-kit browsers?

Tags: css, mobile-safari, mobile-website, mobile-webkit

Is there any pure CSS only solution to keep footer fixed at bottom in Mobile Web-kit browsers?

**Specially in iPhone and Android browser.**

Answer (score 4):

Not really.  Those browsers don't actually use scrolling; they lay out the document on an infinite canvas and then pan across it.  Which is more or less semantic weasel-wording to say that they don't support `position: fixed` in practice.

Answer (score 2):

```
#footer {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ANSpv/).

Works since iOS5.

Comment: @Jitendra I just tried to test it on iPad but jsFiddle's *Result* pane was fully expanded (i.e. no scrollbars).

Comment: Note: this doesn't work on the majority mobile browsers for the reasons Boris outlined below. Will work on the latest iPad however.

Answer (score 2):

Use flexbox :)

```
<body>
    <div id="mainPart"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</body

<style>
body { 
   display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-align: stretch; -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
   display: -moz-box; -moz-box-align: stretch; -moz-box-orient: vertical;
 } 

#mainPart { -webkit-box-flex: 1;  -moz-box-flex: 1; position: relative; z-index: 2;}
footer{
      background-color:#FFC579;
      height:50px;
      position: relative; z-index: 3;
 }
```

Comment: Be aware of some of the issues with flexbox though, namely the change from box-* to flex-*, as well as the other issues covered here: http://oli.jp/2011/css3-flexbox/ Though this is a good use, I really hope that it doesn't become the dominant way to lay things out.

Comment: I agree, and dont believe at this point at least this technique will replace other page layout techniques for desktop browsers, it does work well for simple mobile layouts like the above example. For mainstream layouts I have a cross of a OOCSS a simple grid and inline blocks which make up for almost no layout issues in ie.

Comment: Flexbox is the way. 90%+ browser marketshare support.